# my code runs but does not output anything, why?

Tags: python

This is a shuffling list code I ran but no output. my code looks correct to me.

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

from random import shuffle

shuffle(my_list)

def shuffle_example(new_list):

        shuffle(new_list)
        return new_list

shuffle_example(my_list)
```

Comment: You do not ask your program to output anything. Did you mean to add `print(my_list)` as the last line?

Comment: You're code executes perfectly. Just add `print(my_list)` to show the output

Comment: That's because you haven't printed the result to the console. Try print(shuffle_example(my_list))

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `print(shuffle_example(my_list))` in order to print in the console the result returned by your function.

Answer (score 0):

Here your answer

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

from random import shuffle

shuffle(my_list)

def shuffle_example(new_list):

        shuffle(new_list)
        return new_list

print(shuffle_example(my_list))
```

Comment: i thought their is a way to use the return keyword without print statement?

Answer (score 0):

You're program is never asked to output something. You need to add a `print` statement in order to output something.
Replace replace `shuffle_example(my_list)` with `print(shuffle_example(my_list))`.